# Querying a LINQ to XML feed in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML which I load via `XDocument.Load(uri)` or `XElement.Load(uri)`. I am having trouble getting a collection of `<asset>` elements via LINQ.

Here is a snippet of the XML I'm trying to query:

```
<assetCollection xmlns="tag:aisle7.net,2009:/api/1.0">
      <title>All Assets</title>
      <description>Collection containing all assets in the system</description>
      <resourcePath>/us/assets/~all</resourcePath>
      <link rel="self" href="http://web.aisle7.net/api/1.0/us/assets/~all?apikey=1234567890&amp;Format=XML" />
      <link rel="first" href="http://web.aisle7.net/api/1.0/us/assets/~all?apikey=1234567890&amp;Format=XML" />
      <link rel="next" href="http://web.aisle7.net/api/1.0/us/assets/~all?apikey=1234567890&amp;Format=XML&amp;page=2" />
      <link rel="last" href="http://web.aisle7.net/api/1.0/us/assets/~all?apikey=1234567890&amp;Format=XML&amp;page=66" />
      <updated>2011-03-01T19:01:49.667Z</updated>
      <assets>
        <asset>
          <title>Homeopathy</title>
          <resourcePath>/us/assets/toc/homeopathy</resourcePath>
          <link rel="alternate" href="http://web.aisle7.net/api/1.0/us/assets/toc/homeopathy?apikey=1234567890&amp;Format=XML" />
          <updated>2011-03-01T19:01:49.667Z</updated>
        </asset>
        <asset>
          <title>What Is Homeopathy?</title>
          <resourcePath>/us/assets/generic/what-is-homeopathy_13615_1</resourcePath>
          <link rel="alternate" href="http://web.aisle7.net/api/1.0/us/assets/generic/what-is-homeopathy_13615_1?apikey=1234567890&amp;Format=XML" />
          <updated>2011-03-01T19:00:17.680Z</updated>
        </asset>
    ...
```

And here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
Dim uri As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Aisle7_Index_Url"))

Dim assets = (From a In XElement.Load(uri)
                               .Element("assets")
                               .Elements("asset")
             Select a)

For Each asset In assets
  Console.WriteLine(asset)
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Dim assets = From a In XElement.Load(uri).Descendants("asset") Select a
```

or

```
Dim assets = From a In XDocument.Load(uri).Root.Element("assets").Elements("asset") Select a
```

Comment: No dice. Debugging 'assets' shows the message "Exception of type 'System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugViewEmptyException' was thrown." in the inspector. Any ideas?

Comment: The second snippet you just posted throws a NullReferenceException :(

Comment: @Mark apparently it does not like your `xmlns="tag:aisle7.net,2009:/api/1.0"' . If I remove that, both snippets work fine.

Comment: I just discovered that myself...any way to have LINQ ignore the namespace?

Comment: Turns out you can import a namespace:

Imports <xmlns="tag:aisle7.net,2009:/api/1.0">

Dim uri As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Aisle7_Index_Url"))

Dim assets = From a In XElement.Load(uri).<assets>.<asset> Select a
 
For Each asset As XElement In assets
  Console.WriteLine(asset)
Next

Comment: @Mark cool. also check out this post http://bohu7.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/removing-default-namespaces-from-an-xdocument/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the version using xml literal syntax:

```
Dim xml = XElement.Load(uri)
Dim q = From a In xml.<assets>...<asset> 
        Select a
```